# Change field background color after data is entered

Tags: javascript, css

Guys i'm newbie in Javascript, so sorry for this question...

I need to make input field different colour after enter data, by Javascript or CSS...any help would be good...  Thank you guys!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please refer to the help-center > asking, on how to ask questions. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can setup an onchange event on the inputboxes and set the color using javascript/jquery.

refer: https://api.jquery.com/change/

Set background color/color, using

```
$('elem').css('background', 'colorname');
```

or

```
$('elem').attr('style', 'background:colorname');
```

refer: http://api.jquery.com/css/
       http://api.jquery.com/attr/

hope that helps!